# Bringing back the old front page with custom CSS: a guide

Tags: discussion

As mentioned [in a recent meta question](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/5230), the Stack Exchange development team pushed changes to the front page affecting how views, vote counts, and answer counts are displayed. A few hours ago, these changes unfortunately also made their way into the questions page.

Despite being met by a strong disgust by the community with respect to these changes, the Stack Exchange team has apparently decided to [wilfully ignore these complaints](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/375808).

Is it nevertheless possible to revert these changes on the user side by using custom CSS or user scripts?

Comment: I think ([meta-tag:user-scripts]) would definitely be a suitable tag here. Maybe also ([meta-tag:design])? (I have asked also in [MO editors' lounge](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/10243/2022/2/9) about the choice of tags.)

Answer (score 10):

One can use Phil Brown's custom CSS [here](https://stackapps.com/questions/9296) to get part of the older layout back:

[image]

Denis Nardin's [previous CSS](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/a/4032) partially works (quote backgrounds are still coloured gray and accepted answer backgrounds are still coloured green), but the [brown/green/dark green] style for answers broke. as the css class name for unanswered questions (.status.unanswered) got merged with the one for votes (.s-post-summary--stats-item).

Here's a Franken-CSS that combines the above two styles:

```
/** Container **/

.s-post-summary {
  padding-left: 8px;
}

/** Stats grid **/

.s-post-summary--stats {
  display: grid;
  width: unset;
  grid-template-areas:
    "score answers views"
    ". bounty ."
    ;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr); /* change to 3 for views */
  column-gap: var(--s-post-summary-stats-gap);
  row-gap: var(--s-post-summary-stats-gap);
  align-content: start;
  align-items: center;
}

.s-post-summary--stats .s-post-summary--stats-item,
.s-post-summary--stats .s-post-summary--stats-item.has-answers {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 4px;
  width: 60px;
}

/** State grid items **/

.s-post-summary--stats .s-post-summary--stats-item .s-post-summary--stats-item-number {
  font-size: larger;
  margin-right: 0 !important;
}

.s-post-summary--stats .s-post-summary--stats-item:nth-child(1) {
  grid-area: score;
  border: none;
  background-color: #eee;
  border-radius: 0px;
  color: #3b4045
}

.s-post-summary--stats .s-post-summary--stats-item:nth-child(2) {
  grid-area: answers;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 0px;
  background-color: #833700;
  color: #FFF
}

.s-post-summary--stats .s-post-summary--stats-item.has-answers {
    background-color: #65be00;
    color:#FFF;
}


.s-post-summary--stats .s-post-summary--stats-item:nth-child(3) {
  grid-area: views;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 0px;
}

.s-post-summary--stats-item.has-bounty {
  grid-area: bounty;
}

.s-post-summary--stats .s-post-summary--stats-item.s-post-summary--stats-item__emphasized {
  color: var(--fc-light);
}

/** Tags **/

.post-tag.s-tag__watched {
  padding-left: 0.5em;
}

.post-tag.s-tag__watched:before {
  content: none;
}

/** Hide unwanted elements **/
.s-post-summary--stats .iconCheckmarkSm,
.s-post-summary--meta .s-avatar {
  display: none;
}

.s-post-summary--stats-item.has-accepted-answer {
    color:#FFF;
    background-color: #177d00;
}

/* Part of Denis Nardin's Original CSS (some of it merged above) */

/* Background for accepted answers */
div.accepted-answer {
    background-color: #e0ffe0;
}

/* Blockquote colors (needed for contrast with the accepted answer background) */
blockquote {
    background-color:#dadada;
    border-left:2px solid #ffeb8e
}

/* Background on questions with watched tags in the question list */
.question-summary.tagged-interesting {
 background-color: #fff5deb3;
}
```

It gives the following result:

[image]

To enable it, follow the steps below:

1. Install a browser extension allowing you to load custom CSS onto pages, such as Stylus ([Firefox Link](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/styl-us/), [Google Chrome link](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/stylus/clngdbkpkpeebahjckkjfobafhncgmne?hl=en)).
2. Go to the MathOverflow homepage and click the Stylus icon:
   [image]
3. Go to "Write style for: mathoverflow.net/this URL".
4. You'll be met by this screen:
   [image]
5. Paste the above CSS into the "Code 1:" section.
6. Save via the left sidebar.
7. Everything should now be working again.

Comment: If you have any improvements in mind, feel free to directly edit the answer above.

Comment: Thank you very much! This is SO much better.

Answer (score 7):

Complaints about the new design are not limited to MathOverflow, and [Stack Apps](https://stackapps.com/) has two options to bring back the old design for all Stack Exchange sites; the aforementioned [Userstyles to (semi) revert the new Top Questions design](https://stackapps.com/q/9296/34061) by Phil Brown and [LegacyQuestions - Bringing back the old questions design](https://stackapps.com/q/9293/34061) by Spectric.

[image]